# How to retrieve all data using relation?

Tags: php

i have three tables

```
users
posts
comments
```

my question is how to retrieve user post and post comments in single query .

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question answer has already given by @ Nicklas Kevin Frank .

for getting following error FatalErrorException in Model.php line 867: Class 'Post' not found  error ,in your model class modify your hasmany to this: App\User

```
<?php

class User extends Model
{

public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

}
```

in posts model

```
<?php

class Post extends Model
{

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }


}
```

in comments model

```
<?php

class Comment extends Model
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

and in your controller

```
$data = User::findOrFail(1)->posts()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
User::find($id)->with('posts','posts.comments')->get();
```

This way you get a user, and his posts and comments on said posts.

To only access posts which belongs to a user you must do the following:

```
User::find($id)->with('posts')->get();
```

Comment: ,thank you for answering . i have added your code in user controller index method as $data=User::find(1)->with('posts','posts.comments');
 
print_r($data); but it will print useless output

Comment: getting following error FatalErrorException in Model.php line 867: Class 'Post' not found

Comment: still same .i have updated my question with UserController.php

Comment: And your post class is actually positioned in the `App/` folder of your project?

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with your namespaces. Check your namespaces and ensure that all classes have a namespace that describes the directory path they are put into.

Comment: @ Nicklas,User::find(1)->with('posts','posts.comments')->get(); retrieve all users detail instead of particular user