# How to retrieve all data using relation like outer join?

Tags: php

Based on below question answers I am able to retrieve data of particular table but  not all three table data in single array .
 [How to retrieve all data using relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716521/how-to-retrieve-all-data-using-relation-in-laravel-5-1/31717976#31717976)

I tried following ways

1. This will retrieve all users data instead of particular user

   ```
   User::find(1)->with('posts')->get();
   ```
2. This will retrieve only post detail not user table

   ```
   $data = User::findOrFail(1)->posts()->get();
   ```

Please help me to retrieve all data of three tables in single user in single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will get the user with id one with all posts.

```
$data = User::findOrFail(1)->load('posts');
```

or

```
$data = User::with('posts')->findOrFail(1);
echo "Username:" . $data->name;
foreach($data->posts as $post) {
    echo $post->title;
    echo "Comments:";
    foreach($post->comments as $comment) {
        echo $comment->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer .how to echo each data .i can able to print data using print_r().

Comment: i need to display username including user posts title ?

Comment: you can pass them to a view and then loop through the posts.

Comment: ya i tried loop like     foreach($data as $dats){
  echo $dats->username.'<br>';
  echo $dats->post_desc.'<br>';
  } but it print only username but post_desc not displaying

Comment: the posts as saved in $data->posts

Comment: Nice. If you need more help check out https://laracasts.com/. They have great tutorials.

Comment: ya. i am following that site .

Comment: Even not if you return the $data object so it's printed in json? Also check if you have any comments connected to the posts.

Comment: ,thank you . i tried before posting like that way but didnt worked .i copied your answer it worked perfectly.

Comment: The `posts` will be a `Collection` instance. you can just use `$data->posts->each(function($model) { ... });` to iterate. Much cleaner than a foreach loop.

Comment: or you use blade with @foreach($data->posts as $post)